# Reset Core Data Bool for All Objects

Tags: swift, core-data

I would like to set the bool value to false for every object in my core data entity.

This is how I am currently setting an individual value in core data:

```
func updateFriendSaidHi(friend: Friends, in context: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()){
        context.performAndWait {
            // Update value to true in core data
            friend.saidHi = true
            saveToPersistentStore()
        }
    }
```

You could loop through each item in the entity but I'm guessing there's a better way to do this.

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the attributes of all records with Key-Value Coding

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Friends> = Friends.fetchRequest()
context.performAndWait {
    do {
       let friends = context.fetch(request)
       (friends as NSArray).setValue(true, forKey:"saidHi")
       saveToPersistentStore()
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

Comment: This throws an error at friends.setValue saying that "Value of type '[Friends]' has no member 'setValue'"

Comment: My bad, you have to bridge cast the Swift array to `NSArray`. I updated the answer.